# Type Mismatch: Date vs Boolean in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to display the max date when two of the other conditions meet:

I am not sure what is the best way to to it is Tableau calculated field

```
{

CASE [Due Date] WHEN  ([Data Type] = "REAL" and [Source] = "MMA")

THEN

{fixed :max([Due Date])}

ELSE "" END

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a calculated field called, say Real_MMA_Due_Date that has a value only under the conditions you want and is null otherwise.

```
IF [Data Type] = "REAL" and [Source] = "MMA" THEN [Due Date] END
```

Then you can display Max(Real_MMA_Due_Date) or Min() as needed. Max() ignores nulls, so it will only consider values that pass your IF condition.

That's a flexible approach since it decouples the choice of aggregation function from the IF conditions, allowing you to use the field in multiple ways.

If instead, you need the MAX() embedded in the calculation for some reason, then wrap MAX() around the whole IF statement as in MAX(IF ... END)